# How to define a static struct and access its members in C?

Tags: c, static, struct, typedef

I defined a static struct in C like this:

```
typedef static struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} Hello;
```

Do I need to initiate the struct before I use it? How to access the variable inside of it?

Comment: This is weird, you can't mix `typedef` and `static`. Are you sure this declaration even compiles? When I tried, I got `error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers` since both `static` and `typedef` count as storage specifiers, and you can't have several.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the struct first, then instantiate it in a static variable

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} Hello;

static Hello hello;
```

Then you can access your data like this :

```
hello.a = 42;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a struct and make an instance simultaneously with:

```
static struct Hello {
  int a,b;
} hi;

struct Hello *test() { return &hi; }
```

However as far as I am aware there's no way to combine this with a `typedef` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The storage class (`static`) is not part of a type definition.

In fact, [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) explicitly forbids putting a(nother) storage class into a `typedef` declaration (§ 6.7.1):

> *storage-class-specifier*: **typedef**  **extern**  **static**  **auto**  **register**
>
> ... At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a
>   declaration.

You can only make an actual object of your struct type `static` (as pointed out by others).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one instance of your structure you can use:

```
static struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} foo;
```

And then, access it directly: `foo.a = 42;`